# Why is Eclipse now knocking my jpda debugger port offline?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, jpda

I've used the tomcat jpda debugger a thousand times and I know I have tomcat setup correctly.  Now, when I go to attach my eclipse debugger to the remote tomcat jpda, it won't attach and also knocks the port offline.

I can confirm the debugger port is listening on the Linux server with netstat -nlp | grep 8000.  As soon as I try to attach from Eclipse, the port is no longer lisening.  Anyone seen this ?

Update: The port comes back after I close Eclipse so it must be partially working, but I see no output in the debug perspective and break points are not hit so something else is up.  Possibly VPN related.

Comment: Could you try to connect tomcat server using `jdb -attach server_ip:8000`? Make sure it's not a network issue.

Comment: It was indeed a network issue.  It's working again now.  Thank you for the jdb tip.